# wrapping in do-while-0 vs wrapping in a ternary operator with (void)0

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-operator

I'm looking at [this macro](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert#L154) within Microsoft's GSL:

```
#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond) \
    (GSL_LIKELY(cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) \
        : gsl::details::throw_exception(gsl::fail_fast( \
            "GSL: " type " failure at " __FILE__ ": " GSL_STRINGIFY(__LINE__))))
```

Let's simplify it to ignore what I don't care about:

```
#define CHECK_1(cond) \
    (cond ? static_cast<void>(0) : do_something() )
```

Now, I would intuitively write something like:

```
#define CHECK_2(cond) \
    do { \
        if (not (cond)) {do_something();} \
    } while(0)
```

My question: Is there any difference between these wrapping mechanisms? Is there perhaps some corner use case where one causes some unintended compilation gaffe, but not the other?

Note:

- This might actually be a C question in disguise, I'm not sure there's any real C++ issue here.

Comment: Well, it's 2 lines of code vs 4, so it's 100% better ;) Seriously though I can't think of a technical reason where one is better then the other.  Looks like a style decision.

Comment: Is there a difference? The compiled code will probably be the same for both. In terms of language 1 is an expression, 2 is a statement. So you can stuff 1 into ternaries and/or chain them using commas I guess? Not that that is actually a good idea.

Comment: @NathanOliver _"Looks like a style decision."_ Agreed from my side. Finally would make that question POB.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: See edit.

Comment: @jakub_d: I actually think there isn't, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obscure. See edit.

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, the edit makes it better. I can't help though having a feeling you have a trend to ask _"slightly odd"_ questions, and even answer odd questions here. No offence, thinking _the odd way_ maybe a great impulse for creativity and innowation.

Answer (score -1):

So, my skillz tell me that `CHECK_1` and `CHECK_2` should be entirely equivalent and only a matter of style. I can't think of why this might not be the case. @NathanOliver seems to agree.

Answer (score -1):

The do while version is a statement while the ternary is an expression. For instance, if assert was defined using a do/while, it couldn't be used in the form

`c1 ? x : c2 ? y : (assert(c3), z)`

On the other hand, only the do while form allows any multistatements macro definitions in C as a ternary requires expressions as operands.

This distinction makes the choice clear in C: ternary if possible as the macro can be used in more situations ; do while otherwise.

In C++, where macros are still needed in certain situations, at least to short circuit parameter evaluation at compile time when a macro is disabled, the do while form is never the best option (IMHO). I tend to prefer either the ternary form or, even more c++ fashioned: wrapping the macro definition in an anonymous lambda called immediately.

Using a lambda enables multi statements macros just as with do while. It is a single expression as with the ternary. It enables type safety when forwarding the macro arguments to the lambda (you need to trust the compiler to inline that part at runtime, and it will). Passing macro arguments to the lambda prevents name collision between the macro arguments and the macro body. In general it provides scope isolation due to lambda capture being disabled by default. It enables converting varargs to parameter packs for flexibility an type safety starting from c++17. Plus you get a clean stack frame in the debugger when breaking inside the macro.